# Type Error Call Back Is not a Function In Nodejs

Tags: node.js, sql-server, async-await

I am using a foreach loop to execute a single query with different variable multiple time by the length of data.I am using async to do this so that I can do this with synchronization. But when I am using callback function I get type-error. After inserting the first row in database its stopped inserting for the error. I have search several solution.But nothing solved my problem. Don't know what to do next.If you can find any solution to this code Thanks in advance.

```
var async = require('async');
async.forEachOfSeries(data, function (dataElement, callback){

            request.input('input_id', mssql.Int,dataElement.id);
            request.input('input_service_name', mssql.VarChar(25),dataElement.service_name );
            request.input('input_msisdn',mssql.VarChar(255),dataElement.msisdn);
            request.input('input_sms',mssql.Text,dataElement.sms);
            //request.input('input_datetime',mssql.DateTime,data[i].datetime);
            request.input('input_smsid',mssql.BigInt,dataElement.smsid);
            request.input('input_status',mssql.VarChar(20),dataElement.status);
            request.input('input_txid',mssql.VarChar(200),dataElement.txid);

request.query("insert into mt_log (id,service_name,msisdn,sms,smsid,status,txid) values (@input_id,@input_service_name,@input_msisdn,@input_sms,@input_smsid,@input_status,@input_txid)", (err, result) => {
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                    callback();            
                  }
                  else{
                    console.log("inserting");
                    callback();
                  }


            });
        }, function(err){
          if(err){
            //handle the error if the query throws an error
          }else{
            //whatever you wanna do after all the iterations are done
          }
        });
```

> Error

```
D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\server.js:109
                    callback();
                    ^

TypeError: callback is not a function
    at request.query (D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\server.js:109:21)
    at _query (D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1347:9)
    at Request.tds.Request.err [as userCallback] (D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:671:15)
    at Request.callback (D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\node_modules\tedious\lib\request.js:37:27)
    at Connection.endOfMessageMarkerReceived (D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:2104:20)
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1084:36)
    at Parser.tokenStreamParser.on (D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:914:14)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:198:13)
    at Parser.parser.on.token (D:\LCT Work\node project\Datashiftingtolct2\node_modules\tedious\lib\token\token-stream-parser.js:27:14)
    at Parser.emit (events.js:198:13)
```

> Here the 109 line is the callback(); in else statement

Comment: It would be easy to tell if you attach the error also.

Comment: I am attaching it right now. @Huzaifa

Comment: i have updated the code with error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the async library v1.5x,  per [the documentation](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/v1.5.2/README.md#foreachofobj-iterator-callback), the function you pass to `async.forEachOfSeries()` has three arguments, not two and the callback arrives in the third argument, not the second.

So, you're trying to call something that isn't a function (thus the error you see), it's actually the `key` argument, not the `callback` argument.

Change this:

```
async.forEachOfSeries(data, function (dataElement, callback){
```

to this:

```
async.forEachOfSeries(data, function (dataElement, key, callback){
```

Comment: thank you very much for your effort .I am trying this.

Comment: Thank you very much @jfriend00. It worked.Thank you so much.